# Python BeautifulSoup find all tags under a certain type of tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an XML file with nested tags as such:

```
<tag1>
  <tag2>text0</tag2>
  text1
  <tag2>text2</tag2>
</tag1>
<tag2>text3</tag2>
text4
<tag1>
  <tag2>text5</tag2>
</tag1>
```

Where I want to get all the content of all the `tag2`, but only if they are contained within a `tag1`. So in this example: `text0`, `text2` and `text5`. And not `text1`.

I'm currently doing this in a double for loop. But files to come will have multiple levels and I want to avoid nesting many for loops.

Here is my code:

```
tag1entries = soup.find_all('tag1')
for tag1entry in tag1entries:
  tag2entries = tag1entry.find_all('tag2')
  for tag2entry in tag2entries:
    do_something(tag2entry.contents)
```

Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), for example, to select `tag2` that is direct child of `tag1` :

```
tag2entries = soup.select('tag1 > tag2')
```

or, to select `tag2` anywhere within `tag1` :

```
tag2entries = soup.select('tag1  tag2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
entry_list = [entry.text for entry in soup.find_all('tag2') if entry.parent.name == 'tag1']
```

which results in:

```
['text0', 'text2', 'text5']
```